# Can I convert this wsHttpBinding to a custom WCF binding that supports streaming?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I'm not very familiar with WCF, but I recently inherited an old API that uses two versions of the following `wsHttpBinding`, and I've been tasked with adding a new API call to it that uses streaming.

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="wsHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="0" receiveTimeout="05:00:00" sendTimeout="05:00:00">
    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="64" maxBytesPerRead="66560" />
    <security mode="None/Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Note: The version for QA uses security mode `None`, while the version for prod uses security mode `Transport`, but otherwise they're the same.

While streaming is not supported for this type of binding, it appears that reliable sessions are not currently being used (assuming the lack of a `<reliableSession>` element means it's disabled), so I'm wondering if it might be possible to convert this to a `customBinding` that works identically but with streaming enabled for the one call that will use it.

I've seen similar questions answered long ago with [BindingBox](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2009/08/bindingbox-convert-wcf-bindings.html), a seemingly very useful tool that is no longer available. I unfortunately haven't been able to find a mirror or the source code, so without this tool, how can I determine if this custom binding is possible, and if so, go about creating it?

Comment: Must the client and server use the same binding in WCF. If you want to use custom binding, both the client and server must use same custom binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I pieced together the following based on [this very old blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/drnick/inside-the-standard-bindings-wshttp) and [the customBinding documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/custombinding). This is the equivalent of `None` security mode; for `Transport` security mode, just replace the `httpTransport` element name with `httpsTransport`.

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="wsHttpStreamBinding" receiveTimeout="05:00:00" sendTimeout="05:00:00">
    <textMessageEncoding>
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="64" maxBytesPerRead="66560" />
    </textMessageEncoding>
    <httpTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="104857600" />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```